# How to recursively get web links without reaching maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup

I've been thinking over this problem for a while now, for a personal project, I need to get any and every link from the specified initial webpages, that isn't an external link i.e, doesn't leave the initial website.
I'm already using bs4 for scraping webpages for links, however I can't find a way to continue doing this for every scraped link without eventually reaching the maximum recursion depth.
My previous attempt consisted of something like this:

```py
link_list = []
link_buffer = ["www.example.com"]

def get_links(current_link):
    new_links = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(current_link, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        if link.has_attr("href"):
            ... # check here if the link does not leave the website
            new_links.append(link)
    return new_links

def get_all_the_links(list_of_links):
    target = list_of_links.pop()
    link_list.append(target)
    ...
    for link in get_links(target):
         ...
         if link not in link_list:
             list_of_links.append(link)
    
    if list_of_links.len() != 0: # recursiveness
        get_all_the_links(list_of_links)
    
get_all_the_links(link_buffer)
```

I also looked over scrapy, however I found it too complicated for what I'm trying to do since I just plan on saving these links to a text file and then processing them later.

Comment: The problem is most likely with circular links. Imagine page A points to page B, and page B points to page A. Then your algorithm is going to cycle forever between pages A and B. Quick fix: maintain a set `already_visited` and only visit links you haven't visited already.

Comment: Sorry, I do already have something similar to that and I've edited my code to reflect it. I believe that my main problem is that the site I want to go through is just actually really big, so I need a more sophisticated approach than just simply crawling through it.

Comment: Don't use recursion. Use an infinite `while` loop which takes a url from a `list` or `Queue` until it is empty. As you parse each page and find new urls, add them to the list/queue. As _Stef_ mentioned, you need to keep track of urls you have visited, so you don't get stuck in a loop. You will also need to normalise the urls. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization

Answer (score 1):

Code sample you've provided is a bit messy. But overall you just need an extra storage variable for visited links and check if link is known already before

```
visited_links = set()
...

def get_all_the_links(list_of_links):
    target = list_of_links.pop()
    if target in visited_links:
         # Ignore the current link and move on to next one.
         get_all_the_links(list_of_links)
    else:
         visited_links.add(target)
         ...
         # process link here...
         ...
```